# Trouble running flutter app on connected device

Tags: android, flutter, adb

I setup android studio, flutter, etc on a new laptop running Ubuntu.  I'm having no luck running my app on a connected android phone.  The same setup on a different laptop with the same phone works perfectly.  When I list devices I get:

```
flutter devices
1 connected device:

Error retrieving device properties for ro.product.cpu.abi:
error: device still authorizing


FA81J1A00396 • FA81J1A00396 • android-arm • Android null (API null)
```

When I run the app I see:

```
flutter run -d FA81J1A00396 ./lib/main.dart 
Error retrieving device properties for ro.hardware:
error: device still authorizing


Launching ./lib/main.dart on FA81J1A00396 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...                                              3.3s
Resolving dependencies...                                          39.4s
error: device still authorizing
Unhandled exception:
Exit code 1 from: adb -s FA81J1A00396 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
#0      _runWithLoggingSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart:352:7)
#1      runCheckedSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart:283:10)
#2      AndroidDevice.lastLogcatTimestamp (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart:507:27)
#3      _AdbLogReader._start (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart:681:41)
#4      _runGuarded (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:805:24)
#5      _BroadcastStreamController._subscribe (dart:async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart:213:7)
#6      _ControllerStream._createSubscription (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:818:19)
#7      _StreamImpl.listen (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:472:9)
#8      FlutterDevice.startEchoingDeviceLog (package:flutter_tools/src/resident_runner.dart:261:71)
#9      FlutterDevice.runHot (package:flutter_tools/src/resident_runner.dart:304:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     HotRunner.run (package:flutter_tools/src/run_hot.dart:295:39)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:405:37)
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:545:18)
#13     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:77:64)
#14     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#15     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#16     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:126:18)
#17     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:639:45)
#18     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:668:32)
#19     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:473:7)
#20     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
#21     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:28:18)
#22     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:294:13)
#23     RunCommand.usageValues (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart)
#24     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:77:64)
#25     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#26     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#27     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:126:18)
#28     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:639:45)
#29     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:668:32)
#30     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:473:7)
#31     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
#32     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:28:18)
#33     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:294:13)
#34     AndroidDevice.targetPlatform (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart)
#35     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:77:64)
#36     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#37     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#38     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:126:18)
#39     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:639:45)
#40     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:668:32)
#41     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:473:7)
#42     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
#43     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:33:20)
#44     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#45     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#46     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:947:23)
#47     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#48     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#49     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:115:13)
#50     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:172:5)
```

I can provide more information to anyone who can help.  Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

There is a closed [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27456) in github's flutter repository, the guy had exactly the same problem as yours but on a `windows` machine, he managed to solve it and close the issue by reinstalling the whole android development environment.I know it is weird solution but it worked for him.

Comment: Yeah I saw that post too so before posting here I reinstalled with no luck.